# Speech translation during an AGORA call

Tags: android, google-api, voice-recognition, agora.io

I need to integrate google translation during **video call from Agora (RTC)**
Needed behaviour: opponent says something, I hear his speech, after that I need to hear his speech again, but translated to selected language.
I use next code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.ENGLISH.toString());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, Locale.ENGLISH.toString());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES, Locale.ENGLISH.toString());

        try {
            speechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But when I try to implement this, I receive ERROR_AUDIO error in calback all the time.
When I put this code out from call, everything is okay

Comment: You can't use google intent while on the call, you need to try an external API.

Comment: What API for example?

Comment: Google streaming speech api

Comment: @Yulia did you get any solution?

Comment: Any update on this?